# data mining with unstructured data how to implement?

Tags: bigdata, data-mining, text-mining

I have unstructured data (screenshot of app) and semi-structured data(screen dumping file), i chose store it in hbase. my goal is find defect or issue on app (meaningfull data). Now, I'd like to apply data mining on these, so that is kind of text mining ? and how can i apply some data mining technical on this data ?

Comment: Screenshot will be image and screen dump will be text data. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, screen dump is xml data which is hieranchy of screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To begin with, you can use rule based approach where you define set of rules which detects the defect scenario.
- Then you can prepare training data set which has many instances of defect, non-defect scenarios. In this step, for each screenshot or screen dump file you collect; you would manually tag it as defect or non-defect.
- Then you can train classifier using this training data. Classifier would try to generalize training samples to predict the output label for the samples not seen in the past.
- Since, your input is non-standard you might need some preprocessing to convert your input to standard form. For example, to process screenshots you might need some image processing, OCR, computer vision libraries.

Comment: Thank Yogi Devendra